# Interface with default method Initialisation

Tags: java, methods, interface, default

An interface with a default method is initialized even if this method is overridden and even if it's not at all invoked.

Example:

```
    public interface I {
    int a = foo();
     default void test1(){
     }
    static int foo(){
        System.out.println("I initialized");
        return 15;
    }
}


    public class C implements I{
     public void test2(){
          System.out.print("C initialized");
      }
}


    public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {    
         C c = new C();
         c.test2();
      }   
}
```

**prints**:

```
I initialized
C initialized
```

What's exactly the problem here?

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: According to JLS 8 in section 12.4.1, this case doesn't trigger an interface initialization

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the field `a`; the compiler doesn't know that you never access it in the implementation. It must run the method to determine the value.

```
int a = foo(); // <-- must run foo.
static int foo(){
    System.out.println("I initialized"); // <-- prints I initialized 
    return 15;
}
```

and

```
a = 15
```

and `test1` has nothing to do with `test2`, but even if it did `foo()` would still need to be evaluated to set `a`.

Comment: But according to the JLS section 12.4.1, the invocation of test2 should initialize the class C and its superclasses but not its superinterfaces.

Comment: [JLS-12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) and scroll down *Example 12.4.1-3. Interface Initialization Does Not Initialize Superinterfaces* and note that `i = 1` prints first (as in your question) and you don't have an interface K here.

Comment: This is because a reference to a static field causes initialization of only the class or interface that actually declares it.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, and how does **this** help you solve it?